# How does an OS communicate with the CPU?

Tags: operating-system, cpu

How does OS communicate with CPU?

There are drivers in the OS, ok I understand that part. OS uses drivers--> communicate--> device controller.

How does the communication happen? Does the OS touch the CPU directly with its commands, or is it using BIOS as the interface?

Let's assume that I will make my own OS. Its only task is to send arithmetic operations to the CPU and print results to the screen.
I will tell the CPU to put memory words to registers, count them, and then put them back to memory. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CPU just runs instructions from memory starting at some offset and then keeps fetching the next instruction and repeating. The bootloader sets up the CPU to start running the OS entry point when your computer starts. Actions like keyboard or mouse input cause interrupts which the interrupt controller use to lookup special code setup by the OS to handle these interrupts. These interrupts are also used to allow the OS to switch which thread is currently running on the CPU using special privileged instructions that can only be run in kernel mode. The interrupt causes the CPU to switch to kernel mode before calling into the OS interrupt handler code so that the OS can use the necessary privileged instructions for controlling various behavior user mode code is not allowed to.

There are a lot of details concerning what registers are used for what purposes and much much more but it would take a whole book to cover everything.

[Here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) is a free book that covers many details at a relatively introductory level.

Answer (score 4):

CPU calls OS for specific tasks using interrupts, and OS uses special privileged CPU registers to program CPU.

For example, when you press key on keyboard, interrupt is generated by hardware. CPU calls interrupt handler function (it is part of OS), which will handle keypress and, for example, pass it into user program.

Other example of frequent OS-CPU interaction is task switching. Most OS uses hardware timer to generate around 100 timer interrupts every second. On this interrupt OS scheduler is called, and sometimes it can switch tasks by changing some CPU registers. In simplest OS & CPUs, scheduler will change SP (stack pointer) and PC (program counter) register. With more complex CPUs it will also reprogram MMU hardware unit of CPU and change many internal control registers.

External hardware usually programmed by drivers by doing PIO writes or writes to mapped PCI space (writes to special addresses of hardware memory).

Comment: So OS give instructions to CPU by putting command or words to registers? how does OS control that register?

Comment: There are special (privileged) instructions in most CPU to work with special CPU registers (e.g. WRMSR in x86). What cpu architecture do you know?

Comment: Ok, x86 has the "IP" (eip, rip) register for program counter. This register has address of the instruction to be executed. So, OS prepares user-space IP register before returning from interrupt. And CPU will fetch memory address, pointed by IP, and decode instruction and execute it.

Comment: Is it then possible to control CPU cores? If I have quad core and I want to core 1 to execute only chosen set of instructions and core2 the rest.

Comment: user3521129, to limit your process to some core, use `taskset` command-line tool or `sched_setaffinity` syscall (linux). To block other tasks to be scheduled on some core, you need additionaly  switch to runtime scheduling policy (in linux: SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR). You can't control CPU core scheduling for "set of instructions", only for processes and threads.